# Symfony 3.0 with Doctrine query builder: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'WHERE'

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have some issues using query builder. First things first I have this repository:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function register($username,$password,$email)
  {
    //A Generic return Object
    $status=array('status'=>true,'data'=>"");

    if(empty($username))
    {
      $status['status']=-1;
      $status['data']='Username not given';
      return $status;
    }

    if(empty($password))
    {
      $status['status']=-1;
      $status['data']='Password not given';
      return $status;
    }

    if(empty($email))
    {
      $status['status']=-1;
      $status['data']='Email not given';
      return $status;
    }

    $token=md5(uniqid(gethostname(),true));

    try
    {


      $user=new Users();

      $user->setUsername($username)
            ->setPassword($password)
            ->setEmail($email)
            //->setActivated(false)
            ->setToken($token);

      $em=$this->getEntityManager();

      $tmp_user=$user->getUsername();
      $tmp_mail=$user->getEmail();
      $query=$em->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.username=?',$tmp_user)
                ->orWhere('p.email=?',$tmp_mail)
                ->getQuery();

      $user=$query->getResult();
      var_dump($user);
      if(!empty($user))
      {
        $em->persist($user);

        $em->flush();
        $status['status']=true;
      }
      else
      {
        $result['data'] = -1;
        $result['status'] = "User exists";
      }

    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $result['data'] = $e->getMessage(); // The exact message of the exception thrown during INSERT
        $status['status']=false;
    }


    return $status;
  }

}
```

What I want to achieve is to check if to check if there are any users with the same username or email. That's why I run:

```
  $tmp_user=$user->getUsername();
  $tmp_mail=$user->getEmail();
  $query=$em->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.username=?',$tmp_user)
            ->orWhere('p.email=?',$tmp_mail)
            ->getQuery();

  $user=$query->getResult();
```

Inside the register function. But the:

```
    echo $e->getMessage();
```

Returns:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'WHERE'
```

Comment: `createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` statement is missing, and your `where` statements must be prepared.

Change your code to :

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p')
    ->where('p.username = :username')
    ->orWhere('p.email = :email')
    ->setParameter('username', $tmp_user)
    ->setParameter('email', $tmp_mail)
    ->getQuery();

$user = $query->getResult();
```

Like this, you have a clean prepared query.

[See the "Bind parameters to your query" chapter of doctrine `QueryBuilder` documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query)

**EDIT**

You need to use the repository like follows :

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p)
    ->select('p')
    //...
```

Or add a `FROM` statement :

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->from('YourEntityNamespace', 'p')
    // ...
```

Comment: Now I get the error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'p.username =': Error: Class 'p' . How I will know the class name?